# Content Filters

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

With the current discussion about 'synth sound design' questions in mind, I have got a question.
Would it be possible and handy for users/contributors to filter the questions on the site.
Although we don't get a lot of new questions, sometimes it would be nice to be able to filter out 'less interesting' questions. Ie. Synth sound questions or not very interesting to me. Protools questions about post production are more my cup of tea.

Answer (score 3):

The functionality to do this already exists. Click on that Favorite tags button on the right hand side of the main Questions page.

You'll get two boxes pop up, one that lets you add Favorite tags, and one that lets you add tags you want to ignore.

I do this on the Arquade - I have most high traffic tags blocked there, so I don't see every question about FIFA, for example.

And on Music.SE, as I am a moderator I don't want to hide any questions, but using the Favourite tags box, I can make sure I see any on guitars (which is my main interest there)

Comment: Great thanks! I completely overlooked  that option!

Comment: And of course we have the up and down voting arrows and the check mark to accept answers :-)

Comment: Yes of course, but i only up or down vote a question if it's a well stated and interesting question or not.

Comment: @ArnoudTraa When you're on that filter and you come across posts where the protools- family wasn't applied correctly, feel free to suggest an edit to remove or change the tag - sounds like you really know the topic, so any cleanup you can manage as you read the daily/weekly bit would be fantastic.